# how can I rename simulator in Xcode 5?

Tags: ios, xcode5

i am using Xcode 5 and want to rename the simulators like for 3.5 inches iPhone 4 or 4s and so on. Please help.I couldn't find anything on web.

Comment: This is only available in Xcode 6

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That feature is only available in Xcode 6. Check out the section [Change the Simulated Device and iOS Version](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/GettingStartedwithiOSStimulator/GettingStartedwithiOSStimulator.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012848-CH5-SW10) in the [iOS Simulator User Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/iOS_Simulator_Guide/iOS_Simulator_Guide.pdf).

[image: Device context menu]

Answer (score 8):

For Xcode 6 or later

- Open Xcode
- Navigate to **window**
- Choose **"Devices and Simulators"**
- Click **"Simulators"**
- Double click on simulator of your choice or right click and rename.

Alternative : 
    **Shift + Command + 2**

Comment: still works with xcode 13.4.1, thanks